# rank error when trying to use an RNN on Shakespeare text

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to create an RNN that can generate Shakespeare like text. However, I keep on getting an error about the rank of my input matrices/datasets. I have tried squeezing the matrices, and changing the dimensions etc., but I cannot figure out why it is not working.

Here is my code:

```
# Get Shakespeare text

import tensorflow as tf
shakespeare_url="https://homl.info/shakespeare"
filepath=tf.keras.utils.get_file('shakespeare.txt',shakespeare_url)

with open(filepath)as f:
    shakespeare_text=f.read()

#Tokenizing shakespeare text

tokenizer=tf.keras.preprocessing.text.Tokenizer(char_level=True)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(shakespeare_text)
max_id=len(tokenizer.word_index)

import numpy as np
encoded=np.array(tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(shakespeare_text))-1

dataset_size=tokenizer.document_count

train_size=dataset_size*90//100
dataset=tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(encoded[:train_size])

#Put dataset object into windows and batches

n_steps=100
window_length=n_steps+1
dataset=dataset.window(window_length,shift=1, drop_remainder=True)

dataset=dataset.flat_map(lambda window: window.batch(window_length))

batch_size=32
dataset=dataset.shuffle(10000).batch(batch_size)
dataset=dataset.map(lambda window: (window[:,:-1],window[:,1:]))

dataset=dataset.map(lambda X_batch, Y_batch: (tf.one_hot(X_batch, depth=max_id), Y_batch))

new_dataset=dataset.map(lambda X_batch, Y_batch: (tf.squeeze(X_batch),tf.squeeze(Y_batch)))

dataset=dataset.prefetch(1)

new_dataset=new_dataset.prefetch(1)

#make model

model=tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    
    #tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=[batch_size,None,max_id]),
    
    tf.keras.layers.GRU(128, return_sequences=True, stateful=True, dropout=0.2,recurrent_dropout=0.2,
                       batch_input_shape=[batch_size,None,max_id],name='gru_1'),

    tf.keras.layers.GRU(128, return_sequences=True, stateful=True, dropout=0.2,recurrent_dropout=0.2,name='gru_2'),
                        #batch_input_shape=[batch_size,100,max_id]),
    
    tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(tf.keras.layers.Dense(max_id,activation='softmax',name='time_layer'))
    
   ])


class ResetStatesCallback(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def on_epoch_begin(self,epoch,logs):
        self.model.reset_states()

model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer="adam")
model.fit(new_dataset, epochs=50, callbacks=[ResetStatesCallback()])
```

I have tried passing `dataset` and `new _dataset`, both without success.

The Error is below:

```
Epoch 1/50
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-329-28b67720fd03> in <module>
      1 model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer="adam")
----> 2 model.fit(new_dataset, epochs=50, callbacks=[ResetStatesCallback()])

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
    106   def _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
    107     if not self._in_multi_worker_mode():  # pylint: disable=protected-access
--> 108       return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
    109 
    110     # Running inside `run_distribute_coordinator` already.

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
   1096                 batch_size=batch_size):
   1097               callbacks.on_train_batch_begin(step)
-> 1098               tmp_logs = train_function(iterator)
   1099               if data_handler.should_sync:
   1100                 context.async_wait()

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwds)
    778       else:
    779         compiler = "nonXla"
--> 780         result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
    781 
    782       new_tracing_count = self._get_tracing_count()

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
    821       # This is the first call of __call__, so we have to initialize.
    822       initializers = []
--> 823       self._initialize(args, kwds, add_initializers_to=initializers)
    824     finally:
    825       # At this point we know that the initialization is complete (or less

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in _initialize(self, args, kwds, add_initializers_to)
    695     self._concrete_stateful_fn = (
    696         self._stateful_fn._get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(  # pylint: disable=protected-access
--> 697             *args, **kwds))
    698 
    699     def invalid_creator_scope(*unused_args, **unused_kwds):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(self, *args, **kwargs)
   2853       args, kwargs = None, None
   2854     with self._lock:
-> 2855       graph_function, _, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
   2856     return graph_function
   2857 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _maybe_define_function(self, args, kwargs)
   3211 
   3212       self._function_cache.missed.add(call_context_key)
-> 3213       graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
   3214       self._function_cache.primary[cache_key] = graph_function
   3215       return graph_function, args, kwargs

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _create_graph_function(self, args, kwargs, override_flat_arg_shapes)
   3073             arg_names=arg_names,
   3074             override_flat_arg_shapes=override_flat_arg_shapes,
-> 3075             capture_by_value=self._capture_by_value),
   3076         self._function_attributes,
   3077         function_spec=self.function_spec,

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in func_graph_from_py_func(name, python_func, args, kwargs, signature, func_graph, autograph, autograph_options, add_control_dependencies, arg_names, op_return_value, collections, capture_by_value, override_flat_arg_shapes)
    984         _, original_func = tf_decorator.unwrap(python_func)
    985 
--> 986       func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
    987 
    988       # invariant: `func_outputs` contains only Tensors, CompositeTensors,

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in wrapped_fn(*args, **kwds)
    598         # __wrapped__ allows AutoGraph to swap in a converted function. We give
    599         # the function a weak reference to itself to avoid a reference cycle.
--> 600         return weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
    601     weak_wrapped_fn = weakref.ref(wrapped_fn)
    602 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    971           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    972             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
--> 973               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
    974             else:
    975               raise

ValueError: in user code:

    /Users/dariyankhan/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:806 train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    /Users/dariyankhan/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:796 step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    /Users/dariyankhan/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:1211 run
        return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    /Users/dariyankhan/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2585 call_for_each_replica
        return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
    /Users/dariyankhan/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2945 _call_for_each_replica
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    /Users/dariyankhan/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:789 run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    /Users/dariyankhan/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:747 train_step
        y_pred = self(x, training=True)
    /Users/dariyankhan/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py:976 __call__
        self.name)
    /Users/dariyankhan/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/input_spec.py:168 assert_input_compatibility
        layer_name + ' is incompatible with the layer: '

    ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_34 is incompatible with the layer: its rank is undefined, but the layer requires a defined rank.
```

Comment: Why do you have input shape as `[batch_size, None, max_id]`?

Comment: Just in case the shape of the input changes

Comment: If your data is text use the embedding layer to generate embeddings or use padding to make all your input of the same size. You cannot pass `None` to your `input_shape`.

Comment: I used a one-hot encoder instead of embedding because there are only 39 characters. I also checked and all of the training dataset inputs have the shape (32,100,39), while the outputs have the shape (32,100). I tried changing `None` to `100` but I still got the same error.